# Using XSLT to change xml in a complex schema

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been able to successfully change the 'pbcoreRightsSummary' tag to 'notes' with this formula in xml documents that have no metadata schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">  
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="pbcoreRightsSummary">
    <notes>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </notes>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But when I apply it to a document with these specifications:

```
xmlns="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html 
    http://pbcore.org/xsd/pbcore-2.0.xsd"
```

I get nothing. Please advise?

```
    UPDATE:
```

So, I added the namespaces to the XSLT, as suggested below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html http://pbcore.org/xsd/pbcore-2.0.xsd">  
        <xsl:output method="xml"/>
        <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="pbcoreRightsSummary">
            <notes>
                <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/>
            </notes>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I still can't seem to change this document (I use Oxygen XML Editor 14.0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <pbcoreCollection xmlns="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html         http://pbcore.org/xsd/pbcore-2.0.xsd">
       <pbcoreDescriptionDocument>
          <pbcoreAssetType>Media Object</pbcoreAssetType>
          <pbcoreAssetDate dateType="Created">1970</pbcoreAssetDate>
          <pbcoreIdentifier source="CAVPP" annotation="Object Identifier">000028</pbcoreIdentifier>
          <pbcoreTitle titleType="Main">Case for Population Control</pbcoreTitle>
          <pbcoreTitle titleType="Series"/>
          <pbcoreDescription/>
          <pbcoreRightsSummary>
             <rightsSummary annotation="Copyright Statement">Digital recordings from this collection may be accessed freely. </rightsSummary>
          </pbcoreRightsSummary>
       </pbcoreDescriptionDocument>
    </pbcoreCollection>
```

Comment: I'm not sure from your question what appears in the xsi:schemaLocation attribute. I reformatted without knowing exactly how it looks. But it may be because your XML does not comply to the schma, or that the schema is not found, and thus your transformer can't work on an XML that couldn't be parsed properly.

Comment: Can you tell us what XSL transformer you use ?

Comment: I use Oxygen XML editor version 14.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html" xmlns:foo="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html http://pbcore.org/xsd/pbcore-2.0.xsd">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="foo:pbcoreRightsSummary">
        <xsl:element name="notes">
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a namespace for the pbcoreRightsSummary element. XSLT matches against the null namespace by default (and not the 'prefixless' namespace in your XML document).

Comment: I'm not sure it is the problem since when I try his XSL with Saxon 9.4, I don't find any problem generating the output either with an XML that contains namespace declarations or with one that doesn't.

Comment: I listed the new attempt with namespaces above, but so far have not been able to achieve the transformation.